# Bat para finalizar processo e fechar aplicativo na area de trabalho

Tags: java, batch

Na empresa que trabalho temos um aplicativo chamado Socket desenvolvido em java para executar arquivos no navegador, porem preciso de um bat para que mate o processo e feche o icone do aplicativo e inicie ele novamente, porem ele nao aceita ficar com 2 socket aberto, eu consegui fazer para que mata o processo e inicia ele novamente, porem quando ele inicia da o erro de ficar com dois socket aberto, preciso de um bat que feche o icone e quando inicializar abra novamente, esse icone fica junto a barra de tarefas ao lado do auto falante, espero ter explicado corretamente.

```
@echo off
taskkill /F /IM conhost.exe (nome do processo)
C:\SOCKET\ExecuteAppCaixa.jar (caminho para abrir)
pause
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Vocês usam um mecanismo de arquivo para não ter duas instancias do SOCKET?

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade não são dois processos que ficam abertos no lado do relógio e sim o  Explorer que mantém os ícones como se os dois estivessem abertos, mas na verdade só tem um.

Até o momento a unica forma de fazer o ícone do processo que não está mais ativo desaparecer é colocando o ponteiro do mouse em cima do ícone ou reiniciando o Explorer com os seguintes comandos:

```
taskkill /F /IM explorer.exe
explorer.exe
```

ou apenas:

```
tskill explorer
```

> Obs: No seu arquivo tem no final o comando `pause` que faz com que seja necessário que o usuário pressione qualquer botão para sair da tela, caso queira colocar o comando para ser executado por uma tarefa agendada ou mesmo que manualmente sem que haja a necessidade de ver o retorno de cada comando, seria bom remover o `pause` para que a tela não fique aberta, se estiver sendo executada no agendador de tarefas de forma oculta ao usuário o processo `cmd.exe` ficará aberto sem necessidade.